# Creating dashed/dotted border around skinnable container flex/air?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flex4.5

Is their any way we can create dashed/dotted around skinnable container in flex/air?

I tried few things to programatically add, but not successful

Please let me know any work around for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<s:Rect width="500" height="1">
<s:fill>
<s:BitmapFill source="@Embed('/assets/images/dot.png')" fillMode="repeat"/>
</s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

create the dot.png (1x1 pixel)

Comment: Thanks...This will add a line, I want dotted border in all side with corner radius ?

Comment: thats kinda tricky. if ill have to cheat, ill create the 4 corners as image and use the code above to draw the side lines

Comment: it worked thanks.. but lots of cheat. i wonder y flex won't come with this?

Comment: I believe can also do it using FXG (similar to SVG). http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS145DAB0B-A958-423f-8A01-12B679BA0CC7.html